# Eigenvalues calculation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have the following block matrix

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12}\\
M_{21} & M_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$
where $A$ is a $10 \times 10$ matrix and $M_{ij}$ are $5 \times 5$ matrices. I need to calculate the eigenvalues of $A$ what should I do. Kindly help

Comment: What do you know about the $M_{ij}$ ?

Answer (score -1):

If $M_{21} = 0$, by using a [property of block matrix determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), we have:
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} M_{11}-\lambda I & M_{12} \\ 0 & M_{22}-\lambda I \end{pmatrix} = \det(M_{11}-\lambda I)\det(M_{22}-\lambda I) = 0$$
So in this situation, $M_{21} = 0$, the eigenvalues of $M_{11}$, $M_{22}$ are also the eigenvalues of A.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately $M_{21}$ is not zero (0). What should I do in that case?

Comment: @EvansOtieno I think that there is no formula for describing all eigenvalues of $A$ in general.

Comment: This is what I have tried doing and am doubting wether I am correct $det(A-\lambda I_n) = \text{det} (M_{11}-\lambda I_k)\times \text{det} ((M_{22}-\lambda I_{n-k})-M_{21}(M_{11}-\lambda I_k)^{-1}M_{12})=0$